# setAttribs to element class

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, dom, zend-form

I have a zend form which looks like:

```
<div id="first_name-label">
<label class="form-label required" for="first_name">First Name: *</label>
</div>
<div class="form-div">
<input id="first_name" type="text" required="1" value="" name="first_name">
</div>

<div id="middle_name-label">
<label class="form-label required" for="middle_name">Middle Name: *</label>
</div>
<div class="form-div">
<input id="middle_name" type="text" value="" name="middle_name">
</div>
```

what I want to achieve is using jquery I want to setAttribs required='1' to all form elements which has class required in the label. I am quite new to jquery so have a very little idea on it. Any solution with  a little explanation would be a great help.

I have hardcoded the attrib for input id=first_name

Is there any way in zend itself to apply attribs to all the required classes?

Comment: I know It can be easily done using jquery I just dont know how :( . Any Idea on how to achieve it using Zend would be great too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. Note that required is usually formatted like `required = "required"`.

```
$('label.required').each(function(){
    var phor = $(this).attr('for');
    $('#' + phor).attr('required', 1);
});
```

Comment: you made it seem like real easy :). Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Semi-senseless `.map()` implementation. You should probably use elclanrs' `each()` approach, though, for sake of readability.

```
$('label.required').map(function(){
    return $('#' + $(this).attr('for')).get()
}).attr('required', 1).css({border : '1px solid #f00'});
```

​
[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/L826z/)